# How to make ZSH the default shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

I am trying to set ZSH as my default shell, however it keeps reverting back to bash.

I have tried this code:

```
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Also tried these commands without sudo.  Any ideas on what else I need to do.  When running ZSH from within bash it loads up and works fine but I'd like to set it as the default shell.

Comment: quick answer that worked for me: logging out and then logging back in to the desktop session fixed it for me.

Answer (score 565, accepted):

Just using [`chsh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh):

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

**without** `sudo` should work. If you use `sudo` it will change the shell not for your working user but for *root*

Finally, **log out of your computer and log back in**.

Troubleshooting:

- Do you have zsh installed (ii)? `dpkg -l zsh`
- Is your shell set to zsh? Last field of [`grep $USER /etc/passwd`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd)
- Is Zsh a [valid login shell](https://linux.die.net/man/5/shells)? `grep zsh /etc/shells`

Comment: I have the same problem and the answer doesn't solve it

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Check my answer

Comment: you can also run sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh userName

Comment: Note: I had to restart my system before this would take effect.

Comment: no, it did not work.

Comment: @MichaRoon or `chsh username` with or without the `s` flag. Without, the system will ask for the shell. However, the input is, at least in `zsh` without auto-complete. With `s`, it offers the shell options when pressing `tab` in zsh. This seems save even for idiots.

Comment: I get `chsh: PAM: Authentication failure`, and I've tried on several different machines.

Comment: Rebooting on Linut Mint 19.2 is needed to have `zsh` take over. `sudo reboot` gets the job done.

Comment: Please log out and login if not working.

Comment: I used linux homebrew and got this error
` chsh: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/zsh is an invalid shell`
this is the fix: `command -v zsh | sudo tee -a /etc/shells`
https://daton.gitbook.io/daton-mac/iterm2

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04; as the answer says it didn't take effect until I logged out and logged back in.

Comment: Does this solution still use my bash, so if I have some alias in bash will it still load for example?

Comment: When I try it without `sudo` it keeps asking for password

Comment: Doesn'w work for me either :(
I get "chsh: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/zsh is an invalid shell"
if I simply type "zsh" it does start. not sure how to solve this (I've read that simply doing exec zsh in my .bashrc isn't a good idea)

Comment: don't forget to logout and don't use sudo when execute chsh

Answer (score 75):

I found this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/231735/how-do-i-change-my-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh) forum

Open /etc/passwd:

```
sudo vi /etc/passwd
```

Find the line with your username:

```
username:x:1634231:100:Your Name:/home/username:/bin/bash
```

and replace bash with zsh:

```
username:x:1634231:100:Your Name:/home/username:/bin/zsh
```

Log out and log in back for the changes to take effect.

Comment: You should be very careful with this approach - it's not usually the best idea to go mucking around with `/etc/passwd`

Comment: Even though I didn't use this method, it helped me verify the effect of `chsh -s \`which zsh\``

Comment: To **Log out and log in back** is very important step. Maybe it is should even be somehow emphasized.

Answer (score 49):

You may also do this:

open your bashrc file in your favourite editor

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

then add the line below top of the file

```
exec zsh
```

It will execute the command every time you load the terminal and run your zsh shell.

Comment: and it will also break all your non-interactive jobs (`scp` for example).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but changing `/etc/passwd` or `chsh` are better solutions and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks that did it. @Timo I did the change on /etc/passwd and or chsh but my default kept going back to bash. I added exec zsh as per posted response and it worked.

Comment: Adding exec zsh is most likely going to break your Gnome Shell session.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me on the work machine with active directory, my username is always not found, whoami works fine, but certain commands such as chsh always cannot locate my username

Comment: editing /etc/passwd is never better for someone who cant read the chsh manpage.

Comment: You saved my day by this answer

Comment: DO NOT TRY THIS............DO NOT TRY THIS.This is the worst ever reply for setting the zsh as default shell. Since i had done this and my system is keep in loop of showing login screen after entering username/password.

Comment: nice walk around, work for me to e.g. start `zsh` automatically on the cluster where i don't have sudo access

Answer (score 19):

I had an issue with permissions to change shell under the current user but next helps me (you should set correct 'zsh' folder for your computer):

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh <myUserName>
```

Comment: very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If zsh is not /bin/zsh then chsh won't work. On Ubuntu it is /usr/bin/zsh. so doing `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh` or `` chsh -s `which zsh` `` should work. Also need to re-login to desktop session.

Comment: On my Ubuntu VPS it's /bin/zsh

Comment: On my Ubuntu, I see it in both `/bin/zsh` and `/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: On mine (14.04, with zsh from main repo), there are two zsh's, and they are both two-layer symlinks: /usr/bin/zsh -> /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin -> /bin/zsh5 and /bin/zsh -> /etc/alternatives/zsh -> /bin/zsh5

Answer (score 2):

Strange, the "accepted" answer didn't work for me as I got

```
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

To solve this issue edit your /etc/passwd and make sure it points to the zsh location. (You can find this by running "which zsh")  In my case my user called "webmaster" looked like this:

```
webmaster:x:1001:1001:webmaster,,,:/var/www/webmaster:/usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: I believe it's supposed to ask for a password. I got the same error on my previous mint install. Current one worked fine though

Comment: [Someone else](https://serverfault.com/q/500865/403609) had the same problem, and it turned out they had ran `chsh -s zsh`, which made their passwd entry incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As well as chsh (or editing /etc/passwd, which does the same thing), you might need to edit the settings in your terminal emulator (Gnome terminal, Konsole, xfce4-terminal, etc).  Your profile will probably have a login shell, which will be run when you open a new tab instead of the shell in /etc/passwd.
In Konqueror it's `Settings` | `Edit Current Profile` | `Command`.

Comment: I have been following this [guide](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH) quite often. Somehow on kde plasma 5.27 with Konsole it does work a bit different. Instead of a logout, I needed to restart for `chsh`-changes to take effect. I believe you do *not* need to create a new profile with `zsh` as the default shell. Stuff started working for me after the restart