# 'echo $SHELL' returns 'fish' when I'm using 'zsh'

Tags: environment-variables, zsh, fish

First I installed `fish` and then I wanted to test `zsh` so I installed it. Actually I'm using `zsh` and it works perfect (at the moment): I can switch themes, enable plugins, etc...

But when I do:

```
echo $SHELL
```

it should return `/bin/zsh`, and by surprise it returns `/usr/bin/fish`

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04. Is it ok, or should I fix it?

Comment: @kos, It's similar but not the same. He asks how to switch from zsh to bash, while I'm already using zsh as I wanted. It's just this output that I don't understand.

Comment: Well the linked question is a superset of your question: it asks why that happens *and* how to change that (not how to switch from Zsh to Bash), and has a good answer: so I'd say this question fits all the requirements to be closed as a duplicate of that question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @kos, you're right. The answer you linked contains a reference of the file `/etc/passwd`. Now I also found this related one with very interesting information about `chsh` command and the mentioned file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195361/chsh-s-usr-bin-zsh-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SHELL` always (well, if not set manually) expands to the login shell (defined in `/etc/passwd`) of the user, not necessarily the shell user currently using.

You can cross check with:

```
grep -Po '^username:.*:\K[^:]+$' /etc/passwd
```

Replace `username` with your real username.

If you want to change your login shell, modify `/etc/passwd` or better use `chsh`:

```
chsh -s /path/to/shell username
```

Comment: Well, it returns the same as before: `/usr/bin/fish`. When I change it with the command `chsh` (as root), it returns: «Authentication error».

Comment: Opening the file `/etc/passwd` I can see the first line: «root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh5»

Comment: @Gerard Exactly, it returned `/usr/bin/fish` expectedly..check for which user you are running the command..

Comment: So it's the expected output... I thought it was wrong. Then it's everything ok. Thanks! :)

Comment: I edited manually the file `/etc/passwd`, the line 34 where there's my username `:/home/gerard:/usr/bin/fish`, to this: `:/home/gerard:/usr/zsh`, I restarted the system and now it returns the right shell. I don't think that `fish` was the expected result because I deleted it before installing zsh.

Comment: @Gerard What i wrote in the answer is correct..perhaps you are tripping around the usernames as i mentioned in my last comment..

Comment: In fact, heemayl, I did a mistake in my last answer. The right path to the zsh shell is `/bin/zsh/` instead of `/usr/zsh`. To be honest, I don't understand how the username works on it (and I only have one user). After editing manually `passwd` and logging in, the command `chsh -s /bin/zsh` works without errors and `echo $SHELL` returns the same as listed in `/etc/shells`. I think everything is fixed. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Gerard, get out of the habit of manually editing files. Get out of the habit of working as root. You're inevitably going to make an accident and screw up your system. It happens to everybody. Get comfortable using the correct commands (`chsh`) as the right user. Get comfortable using the `sudo` command when you *temporarily* need to elevate your privileges.

Comment: Yes, trying it as root was a mistake @glennjackman because I didn't understand the scope of the users of the shell. Editing files... Well, I know it was a risk, still I did a backup of the original file. 99% of the times I use `sudo` when it's needed instead of `sudo su`. Thanks for your advices :)