# "chsh: invalid option -- 'l'"

Tags: command-line, default-programs, zsh

I have installed Zsh via running:

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

Using the following  [guide](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH) for installing Zsh provided by oh-my-zsh I attempted to set it as my default shell, namely I ran:

```
chsh -s $(chsh -l | grep "zsh" -m 1)
```

which gave me the error:

```
chsh: invalid option -- 'l'
```

I ran:

```
sudo gedit /etc/shells
```

so I could check that zsh was listed there and it was. I also tried [Florian's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/131838/93125) to a previous question, namely: `chsh -s /bin/zsh` but `echo $SHELL` still returned the same output: `/bin/bash`. `/bin/zsh` does exist on my system if you are wondering, as I tested this by running `/bin/zsh` which started Zsh.

Comment: Just run `chsh`, enter your password and type the path of `zsh` (presumably `/usr/bin/zsh`)

Comment: Fixed the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it using

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

It will prompt you to enter your password. Your default login shell is /bin/zsh now.

`man chsh`

> The chsh command changes the user login shell. This determines the
>   name of the users initial login command. A normal user may only change
>   the login shell for her own account, the superuser may change the
>   login shell for any account

This command will change the default login shell permanently.

#### Why $SHELL not change?!

The SHELL variable is set by the process that logs you in. It is set to the login shell value set in the passwd file (/etc/passwd). It is not meant to reflect the shell you're currently using.

#### To print the shell in use you have to run

```
 echo $0
```

This will shows the shell name used.

#### So how to change Login Shell

use the command `chsh` without options

```
$ chsh 
Password: 

Changing the login shell for maythux
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Login Shell [/bin/bash]:
```

you can enter now your `/bin/zsh`.

Now log out then login again

```
$ echo $SHELL

/bin/zsh
```