# What tool do I need to install to make my terminal show the autocompletion of the command that I'm writing?

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I use Ubuntu on a daily basis, recently I've seen that the terminal on Kali Linux behaves differently from the terminal on Ubuntu... I can see the end of the command that I'm typing based on the history of commands that I've typed like the following:

[image: Picture of terminal showing the visual autocompletion feature]

I know I can use autocompletion by pressing tab, but this feature is something else since I can see the command before pressing tab... That's not a Kali related question too since I just want to replicate this feature on Ubuntu 20.04. Is it a feature that I can easily install on Ubuntu by installing some tool with `apt install`? Or is it a configuration that I need to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kali uses [zsh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/zsh.1.html) instead of `bash` as the default shell and the feature you are referring to is called autosuggestions.

**Before you begin**, you will need to set up `zsh` if you haven't already.

Run the following to install `zsh` and follow the instructions when prompted (it's best to accept the defaults and auto-generate your `zshrc` file):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zsh zsh-syntax-highlighting
zsh
```

---

**For 20.04** or newer, run the following command to install the `zsh-autosuggestions` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zsh-autosuggestions
```

**For Ubuntu 18.04**, you can run the following commands to install the [zsh-autosuggestions repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=shells%3Azsh-users%3Azsh-autosuggestions&package=zsh-autosuggestions) *Keep in mind that the owner of the key may distribute updates, packages and repositories that your system will trust* ([more information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt)):

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:/zsh-users:/zsh-autosuggestions/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/shells:zsh-users:zsh-autosuggestions.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:zsh-users:zsh-autosuggestions/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/shells_zsh-users_zsh-autosuggestions.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zsh-autosuggestions
```

---

**Finally**, run the following commands to add autosuggestions to your `zshrc` file:

```
cp ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrcbackup
echo "source $(dpkg -L zsh-autosuggestions | grep 'zsh$')" | tee -a ~/.zshrc
echo "source /usr/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh" | tee -a ~/.zshrc
```

and don't forget to source your `~/.zshrc` file to apply the changes (if you are in bash or another shell, run the `zsh` command first):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

---

[See here if you want to make zsh the default shell.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131823/how-to-make-zsh-the-default-shell)

Run the following command to search for other plugins, plugin managers, related packages (like fuzzyfinder), and other compatible shells:

```
apt-cache search zsh
```

Comment: and yes, this works in gnome terminal. Gnome terminal uses `bash` by default but to use `zsh` in gnome-terminal just run the command `zsh`. To go back to bash, type `exit` or `bash`.

Comment: To make gnome-terminal always use `zsh` follow [the instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131823/how-to-make-zsh-the-default-shell) for how to make `zsh` the default shell.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted... It seems I can't vote up to your answer because I still don't have 15 of reputation though :)

Comment: @mchid going back to bash with `bash` is not really going back, but going forward to a new bash session while leaving everything before (bash, zsh) running.

Comment: Highly recommended addition to ZSH : https://ohmyz.sh/

Comment: hmm, but what if you want to remain with bash and have this feature? Is that possible?

Comment: @frakman1 It looks like there's something called ble.sh but I'm not familiar with it. There's [an answer here on unix.stackexchage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109366/does-bash-have-similar-features-such-as-fishs-autosuggestions-and-highlighting) that talks about it and a [thread on reddit where the maintainer or dev mentions it](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/iv8u14/syntax_highlighting_andor_autosuggestions_for_bash/).

Comment: This is a great answer! worked for ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

If you like the Kali terminal layout so much like me what I did was to just backup the existing .zshrc file,

```
cp ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrc.bak
```

and I just copied the .zshrc file from my kali backup and ran,

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

And it pretty much worked exactly like in kali

I just put the content of the file here using pastebinit,

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GqtRtdDpQy/

Answer (score 0):

When using `zsh` you can apply syntax highlighting:

(This way you can also check if your command is correct or not/helps as a sort of autocomplete).

```bash
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git

echo "source ${(q-)PWD}/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc
```

Apply to shell:

```bash
source ./zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```