# program that display hints to commands linux

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard

I want to ask is there any program that display hints to commands in terminal (like in background) not like tab?

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable thing that I can think of is autosuggestions, which is used in kali-linux, that is based on commands you've typed before. However, Kali uses ZSH instead of BASH, which is a more complete and offers configurations than BASH shell does. You can read a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1297969/1652872), or look for that information on the internet, Kali developers made that change in 2020.3 version.

Comment: If this was useful please consider tagging this answer as the solution, it will help the community and me, thanks.