# PowerShell-like history auto suggestion for Bash

Tags: bash, 22.04, bash-history, powershell

Microsoft added a neat feature in the 7.3.0 release of PowerShell called [Predictive IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-predictors?view=powershell-7.4#using-predictive-intellisense) which autosuggests commands to enter as you type based on the history. Such a suggestion can be accepted simply by pressing the <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) key.

[image: Predictive IntelliSense description]

[image: Predictive IntelliSense example]

Can a similar effect be achieved in Ubuntu's Bash? I do know I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but it does not seem  as convenient.

Comment: fzf is really neat but if you don't like pressing CTRL+R, are you open to [using zsh instead of bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297990/167115)? `zsh-autosuggestions` looks really similar and if you're not familiar then you can probably see it in use on some newer kali linux tutorials or video demos that show the terminal as zsh with the autosuggestions has been the default on kali for the past few years now.

Comment: This feature is also seen in fish, and zsh-autosuggestions mentioned by @mchid is inspired by the fish one (I use it but it's not some "predictive intelligent" thing, it just shows the most recent command from history matching what you have typed so far) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646375/70524 suggests https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh does the same for bash

Answer (score 5):

There is a replacement for the built-in <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> called [hstr](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr). It allows you to search command history, matching all search tokens at the same time (among other things), and cycle through the results using arrow keys. Here is a short demonstration screen-cast that can also be viewed from [hstr](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) :

[image]

**About:**

Easily view, navigate and search your command history with shell history suggest box for bash and zsh.

**HSTR is included in Ubuntu 21.10 and newer releases. To install run:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hstr
```

**To Install HSTR on Ubuntu 21.04 and older, run:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hstr
```

Then [configure](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) hstr for `bash` :

```
hstr --show-bash-configuration >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

And then use <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

As [also suggested by @muru in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493857/powershell-like-history-auto-suggestion-for-bash/1493973#comment2617463_1493857), there is the [ble.sh ―Bash Line Editor―](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh) that can do what you want. Before installing it, you have to install its dependencies (if not already installed): `git`, `make` (GNU `make`), and `gawk` (GNU `awk`). You can do that with the following command:

```
sudo apt install git make gawk
```

Then, to install `ble.sh` run the following commands:

```bash
git clone --recursive --depth 1 --shallow-submodules https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh.git
make -C ble.sh install PREFIX=~/.local
echo 'source ~/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The above commands will download the repository in your current directory, install it in `~/.local/share/blesh/ble.sh` and add the required line in your `~/.bashrc`.

After that close and reopen your terminal and you should have autosuggestions enabled:

[image: terminal showing autosuggestions]

If you want to uninstall `ble.sh`, follow these steps (from the project's [1.6 Uninstall](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh#16-uninstall) section):

> - Close all the `ble.sh` sessions (the Bash interactive sessions with `ble.sh`)
> - Remove related user data. If you would like to keep them, you can skip these steps.
>
>   - Remove the added lines in `.bashrc`.
>   - Remove `blerc` files (`~/.blerc` or `~/.config/blesh/init.sh`) if any.
>   - Remove the state directory `~/.local/state/blesh` if any.
> - Remove the directory where `ble.sh` is installed. When you use `out/ble.sh` inside the working tree of the git repository, the installed directory is the directory of the repository. When you use `ble.sh` installed by `make install`, the installed directory is `<PREFIX>/share/blesh` where `<PREFIX>` (default: `~/.local`) is the prefix specified to make install in the installation stage. When you use the version extracted from a tarball, the directory created by extracting the tarball is the installed directory.
> - Remove the cache directory `~/.cache/blesh` if any.
> - Remove the temporary directory `/tmp/blesh` if any [ Only needed when your system does not automatically clears `/tmp` ].

Comment: For the highlighting style for the suggested text, you may also check the Q&A at https://superuser.com/questions/1512618.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `fish` might help you with this.
`sudo apt install fish`

then open terminal
right click on it and go to preferences -> Command -> Enable `Run a custom command  instead of shell`

and write `fish` in below input.
Restart terminal and you're good to go :)